# Register another receiver in OnReceive() android

Tags: java, android

I m sending message using SMSManager in OnReceive() method, I want to add sent and delivery report intent for SMSManager, when i registering the receiver in another receiver by programmatically and also by in manifest, its not calling the sent sms receiver.

Is it possible to do in onReceive() or else help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is `IntentReceiver` components are not allowed to register to receive intents. You can't register a new `BroadcastReceiver` in an existing `BroadcastReceiver`.